# PDO Insert writes value of 1 into all fields with bound parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of contacts with the following fields/data types: `contactid` (PK, auto-increment, not null), `fname varchar(50)`, `lname varchar(50)`, `email varchar(50)`, `is_member tinyint(1)` (i.e., boolean), and `createdate date`.

The data is submitted to the same PHP page that the form is on, and the values of the `$_POST` array are packaged into a Contact object and passed to the following function:

```
<?php
    public static function insertContact(Model $model, Contact $contact) {
        $database = new Database();
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO contact (fname, lname, email, is_member, createdate) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email, :is_member, CURDATE())';
        $params = array(
            ':fname' => $contact->getFirstname(),
            ':lname' => $contact->getLastname(),
            ':email' => $contact->getEmail(),
            ':is_member' => intval($contact->isMember())
        );
        $result = $database->query($sql, $params, 'LASTID'); // Will return last inserted ID.
        $model->notify('Added contact ID ' . strval($result) . ' to the database.');
    }
?>
```

This function is called if another function that checks to see if the contact already exists returns `false`. I'm using PDO prepared statements, and everything's working fine for `SELECT` statements, but when I try to execute this `INSERT` statement, I'm running into problems. The `$params` array is correct, and the number of params matches the number of placeholders, but the `is_member` field is causing problems. If the value is `1`, the `INSERT` completes, but the resulting row looks something like this:

```
contactid  fname  lname  email  is_member  createdate
14         1      1      1      1          2014-05-31
```

Has anybody seen this behavior before? Moreover, if the value of `is_member` is `0`, then the query fails entirely with the PDOStatement warning `[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`. What I don't get is that `$params` has the correct number of values to bind to the placeholder tokens.

[UPDATE:] The `$database->query()` method is as follows:

```
<?php
    // Return type is the format in which to return the result of the query.
    public function query($sql, $params, $returnType) {
        if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql)) {
            foreach($params as $key => $value) {
                if($value != 'noParams') {
                    $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
                }
            }
            if($stmt->execute()) {    // execute() returns TRUE on success
                 switch($returnType) {
                     case 'ASSOC':
                         $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                     break;
                     case 'LASTID':
                         $result = $this->connection->lastInsertId();
                     break;
                     // ... more cases, etc.
                 }
             } else {
                 $result = null;
                 die('Error: ' . $this->connection->error);
             }

             return $result;
         } else {
             die('Prepare failed: (' . $this->connection->error . ')');
         }
     }
?>
```

As mentioned, this `query()` method works for prepared statements for `SELECT` operations, however it is exhibiting the aforementioned behavior when trying to do a simple `INSERT`. Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Nobody never seen this behavior before.

Comment: I'd rather ask what does $database->query() function do.

Comment: Show the code for your `$database->query()` method

Comment: @MarkBaker, I have updated the post to include the code for `$database->query()`. I'm given to understand that this is a fairly common approach to use for PDO prepared statements, and that using named placeholders is more straightforward than using positional `?` tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first problem:**

```
if($value != 'noParams') {
```

If value is 0, then this will be a false match because it's a **loose-typed** comparison; so "falsey" type values (`null`, `0.0`, `false`, etc) will give you problems, because it won't bind any falsey values from your array... which explains your `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` error....

make it a strict comparison:

```
if($value !== 'noParams') {
```

**Your second problem:**

Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

At the point where you actually execute the statement, `$value` only has the value from the last iteration of your binding loop, which is the value from the `is_member` array element, which is `1`. That's why you're getting nothing but `1` values for all your bind variables

Change your `foreach` loop to

```
foreach($params as $key => &$value) {
```

So that `$value` is "by reference", and it should then be the correct reference that is bound to each bind var

Alternatively, use `bindValue()` rather than `bindParam()`

**Holistic:**

So for the complete fix

```
foreach($params as $key => &$value) {
    if($value !== 'noParams') {
        $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that worked perfectly! Can't believe I missed that it wasn't binding the reference. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using exec versus query?

in the docs:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

versus
https://www.php.net/pdo.query

bottom line: PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object
while PDO::exec — Execute an SQL statement and return the number of affected rows